Programatically get language-specific information about a symbol for VS Code custom extension
On a JavaScript TextDocument, can I detect if it has a class that extends from an arbitrary other class? If I want to detect a TextDocument that has a class that extends from Animal, the below will suffice.
class Rabbit extends Animal{
}

Or more generally, How do I get more information about a symbol in vscode? Like a variable's type, or function's parameters, or any other information that a symbol could have.
I thought Programmatically get list of all symbols in VS Code workspace for custom extension could be the solution, but it does not provide language-specific information.

why not use a dedicated language parser? Ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241055/11107541
